# Updater created with Inno Setup does not change the application version

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to create an application installer (a big file) and an updater, which is just a small file and contains only files which changed since the previous installation/update. This update file also should increase the number of the application version. I followed this document http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?updateinstall, i.e. I set `CreateUninstallRegKey=no` and `UpdateUninstallLogAppName=no`

Everything works fine except one thing. The updater does not change the version number in the list of installed applications. For example, if I installed the version 1.1.2 with the installer and then ran the updater which has parameter `AppVersion=1.1.3`. The updated files get installed correctly but the version in the list of installed application (in Windows Settings) still shows version 1.1.2.

I tried to change to `UpdateUninstallLogAppName=yes` but this does not affect the version number displayed. When I look into registry, I still can see the number 1.1.2.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change it explicitly in your script.

`CreateUninstallRegKey=no` prevents any updates to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

As the [page you linked to](https://web.archive.org/web/20200612000115/https://jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?updateinstall) *(link to an archive as the page is dead now)* says:

> **The update should not** create a new entry in the Add/Remove Programs list, or **alter the original application's entry**.

---

You can use [`[Registry]` section entry](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) (as your comment below shows) or [`RegWriteStringValue` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regwritestringvalue).